# Discord.py How to make a if this fail function

Tags: discord.py

Hi I have following code

```py
@commands.command(name="playing", aliases=["np"])
    async def playing_command(self, ctx, name: t.Optional[str]):
        player = self.get_player(ctx)
        name = name or player.queue.current_track.title

        async with ctx.typing():
            async with aiohttp.request("GET", LYRICS_URL + name, headers={}) as r:
                #if not 200 <= r.status <= 299:
                    #raise NoLyricsFound

                data = await r.json()   

        if not player.is_playing:
            raise PlayerIsAlreadyPaused

        embed = discord.Embed(
            title="Wird gespielt",
            colour=ctx.author.colour,
            timestamp=dt.datetime.utcnow(),
        )
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=data["thumbnail"]["genius"])
        embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {ctx.author.display_name}", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
        embed.add_field(name="Track title", value=player.queue.current_track.title, inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Artist", value=player.queue.current_track.author, inline=False)

        position = divmod(player.position, 60000)
        length = divmod(player.queue.current_track.length, 60000)
        embed.add_field(
            name="Position",
            value=f"{int(position[0])}:{round(position[1]/1000):02}/{int(length[0])}:{round(length[1]/1000):02}",
            inline=False
        )

        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

But when I run this and the bot cant find a Thumbnail I get the key Error 'thumbnail'

So I tried this

```py
@playing_command.error
    async def playing_command(self, ctx, name: t.Optional[str]):
        player = self.get_player(ctx)
        name = name or player.queue.current_track.title

        async with ctx.typing():
            async with aiohttp.request("GET", LYRICS_URL + name, headers={}) as r:
                #if not 200 <= r.status <= 299:
                    #raise NoLyricsFound

                data = await r.json()   

        if not player.is_playing:
            raise PlayerIsAlreadyPaused

        embed = discord.Embed(
            title="Wird gespielt",
            colour=ctx.author.colour,
            timestamp=dt.datetime.utcnow(),
        )
        embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {ctx.author.display_name}", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
        embed.add_field(name="Track title", value=player.queue.current_track.title, inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Artist", value=player.queue.current_track.author, inline=False)

        position = divmod(player.position, 60000)
        length = divmod(player.queue.current_track.length, 60000)
        embed.add_field(
            name="Position",
            value=f"{int(position[0])}:{round(position[1]/1000):02}/{int(length[0])}:{round(length[1]/1000):02}",
            inline=False
        )

        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

But with this I get errors like

```py
_ClientEventTask exception was never retrieved
future: <ClientEventTask state=finished event=on_message coro=<bound method MusicBot.on_message of <bot.bot.MusicBot object at 0x0000022FEF05E6A0>> exception=CommandInvokeError('Command raised an exception: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "CommandInvokeError") to str')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Neuer Ordner\MusicBot\bot\cogs\music.py", line 637, in playing_command
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=data["thumbnail"]["genius"])
KeyError: 'thumbnail'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'thumbnail'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 71, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Neuer Ordner\MusicBot\bot\cogs\music.py", line 658, in error_command
    async with aiohttp.request("GET", LYRICS_URL + name, headers={}) as r:
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "CommandInvokeError") to str

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 348, in _run_event
    await self.on_error(event_name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Neuer Ordner\MusicBot\bot\bot.py", line 68, in on_message
    await self.process_commands(msg)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Neuer Ordner\MusicBot\bot\bot.py", line 64, in process_commands
    await self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 943, in invoke
    await ctx.command.dispatch_error(ctx, exc)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 422, in dispatch_error
    await injected(cog, ctx, error)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 77, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "CommandInvokeError") to str
```

How to fix this

I just want when the thumbnail function fails that the bot send a embed without thumbnail

Answer (score 0):

To check if a key exists in a `dict` you can use the `in` operator.

```py
>>> "key" in {"key": "value"}
True
```

So just put an `if` around the `set_thumbnail` line.

```py
if "thumbnail" in data and "genius" in data["thumbnail"]:
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=data["thumbnail"]["genius"])
```

If the `if`'s condition is `False` it won't run `set_thumbnail` so it won't add one, like you wanted.